# Cancel queued builds and aborting executing builds using Groovy for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

For Jenkins using a Groovy System Script, is there a way to easily search the build queue and list of executing builds for some criteria (specifically a parameter that matches some condition) and then kill/cancel them?

I cannot seem to find any way to do this, but it seems like it should be possible.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I haven't tested it myself, but looking at the [API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html) it should be possible in the following way:

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def q = Jenkins.instance.queue

q.items.findAll { it.task.name.startsWith('my') }.each { q.cancel(it.task) }
```

Relevant API links:

- http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html
- http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.html

Comment: Note: make sure its a groovy *system* script

Comment: How does one get the job parameters (aka buildVariables?) from a queued task?

Comment: this doesnt kill executing builds

Comment: running builds I killed by https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/2380acfc5df3518ab5b99625734c52da

Answer (score 66):

I know it's kind of an old question, but Google points me to this one. The scripts shown here only remove the jobs from the queue, and don't stop running builds. The following script, just removes everything from the queue and kills all running builds:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList
  import hudson.model.*;
  import jenkins.model.Jenkins

  // Remove everything which is currently queued
  def q = Jenkins.instance.queue
  for (queued in Jenkins.instance.queue.items) {
    q.cancel(queued.task)
  }

  // stop all the currently running jobs
  for (job in Jenkins.instance.items) {
    stopJobs(job)
  }

  def stopJobs(job) {
    if (job in com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) {
      for (child in job.items) {
        stopJobs(child)
      }    
    } else if (job in org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject) {
      for (child in job.items) {
        stopJobs(child)
      }
    } else if (job in org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob) {

      if (job.isBuilding()) {
        for (build in job.builds) {
        build.doKill()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: For me, doStop() worked immediately while doKill did nothing

Comment: But the original request was NOT to remove everything from the queue and stop all jobs: it was to selectively do so.

Comment: It is very effective, but with a side effect: it also deletes entire build history of all jobs that were running at the moment it was used...

Answer (score 62):

Referencie: https://xanderx.com/post/cancel-all-queued-jenkins-jobs/

Run this in Manage Jenkins > Script Console:

```
Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()
```

Comment: This destroys the entire queue of jobs and does not answer the request about stopping 'based on criteria'

Comment: I didn't care for groovy scripts. This solution is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 13):

After some investigation, I came up with this code which works absolutely fine for me. It clears the queue and also aborts all the jobs currently getting executed.

Prerequisites:

1. 'All' view contains all the jobs
2. Use System groovy

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.*

// Remove everything which is currently queued

Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()
def buildingJobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).findAll {
    it.isBuilding()
}

buildingJobs.each {
    def jobName = it.toString()
    def val = jobName.split("\\[|\\]")

    // 'Abort jobs' is the name of the job I have created, and I do not want it to abort itself.

    if((val[1].trim())!='Abort jobs') {
        def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(val[1].trim())
        for (build in job.builds) {
            if (build.isBuilding()) {
                println(build)
                build.doStop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

couldn't add as a comment, but as of today with latest jenkins, Andrey's script (nice) requires another import to work. Executing as system Groovy script.

Jenkins errors and mentions the missing class. I included the url that mentioned the issue:

```
//import hudson.model.*
// per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429050/running-groovy-command-from-jenkins-using-groovy-script-plugin
// requires this now
import jenkins.model.Jenkins 

def q = Jenkins.instance.queue

q.items.findAll { it.task.name.startsWith('my') }.each { q.cancel(it.task) }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution, if you want to run only the newest job of same project from  the build queue and cancel other:

```
def q = Jenkins.instance.queue
//Find items in queue that match <project name>
def queue = q.items.findAll { it.task.name.startsWith('sample_project') }
//get all jobs id to list
def queue_list = []
queue.each { queue_list.add(it.getId()) }
//sort id's, remove last one - in order to keep the newest job, cancel the rest
queue_list.sort().take(queue_list.size() - 1).each { q.doCancelItem(it) }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import hudson.model.*

def queue = Hudson.instance.queue

println "Queue contains ${queue.items.length} items"

queue.clear()

println "Queue cleared"
```

---

paste this in "Script Console" - jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Script Console and hit run.
This helped in clearing the queue and also displays the number that is cleared.

Answer (score 3):

Use the jenkins groovy postbuild plugin:
I think this would be the groovy script:

```
import hudson.model.*  
def q = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getQueue()   
def items = q.getItems()  
for (i=0;i<items.length;i++){  
  if(items[i].task.getName() == "job_name"){  
  items[i].doCancelQueue()  
}   
}
```

Comment: Considering that the script console could be used, or a number of other ways - I am not sure the first statement makes sense - perhaps a few of the methods would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded upon the snippet by [Igor Zilberman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39635794/202504) so that it also aborts running jobs when there is a job in the queue with the same cause (what you see when you hover over the job in the build queue, only looking at the first line). I’m running this as a job with build step “Execute System Groovy Script”.

```
import hudson.model.Result
import jenkins.model.CauseOfInterruption
import jenkins.model.*;

[ // setup job names here
'my-jobname-here'   
].each {jobName ->  
  def queue = Jenkins.instance.queue  
  def q = queue.items.findAll { it.task.name.equals(jobName) }  
  def r = [:]  
  def projs = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { it.name.equals(jobName) }  

  projs.each{p ->  
    x = p._getRuns()  
    x.each{id, y ->  
      r.put(id, y)  
    }  
  }  

  TreeMap queuedMap = [:]  
  TreeMap executingMap = [:]  

  q.each{i->  
    queuedMap.put(i.getId(), i.getCauses()[0].getShortDescription()) //first line  
  }  
  r.each{id, run->  
    def exec = run.getExecutor()  
    if(exec != null){  
      executingMap.put(id, run.getCauses()[0].getShortDescription()) //first line  
    }  
  }  

  println("Queued:")  
  queuedMap.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }  
  println("Executing:")  
  executingMap.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }  

  // First, if there is more than one queued entry, cancel all but the highest one.  
  // Afterwards, if there is a queued entry, cancel the running ones  

  def queuedNames = queuedMap.values();  
  queuedNames.each{n ->  
    def idsForName = []  
    queuedMap.each{ id, name ->  
      if(name.equals(n)){  
        idsForName.add(id)  
      }  
    }  
    if (idsForName.size() > 1){  
      println("Cancelling queued job: "+n)  
    }  
    // remove all but the latest from queue  
    idsForName.sort().take(idsForName.size() - 1).each { queue.doCancelItem(it) }  
  }  
  executingMap.each{ id, name ->  
    if(queuedMap.values().contains(name)){  
      r.each{rid, run->  
        if (id == rid){  
          def exec = run.getExecutor()  
          if(exec != null){  
            println("Aborting running job: "+id+": "+name)  
            exec.interrupt(Result.ABORTED)  
          }  
        }  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}  
return "Done"
```

Answer (score -2):

To control Job build queue, you can use this Plugin also:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Block+queued+job+plugin

- To block job when last build of defined target project is in building
  status
- To block job when last build of defined target project has result