# Jenkins-Groovy script error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

When I tried to execute the following Groovy script in Jenkins console, the below error occurs.

```
import hudson.model.*

/* removed as per comments
// get current thread / Executor
def thr = Thread.currentThread()
// get current build

import hudson.model.*  
def build = thr?.executable
*/

// get parameters
def parameters = build?.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters
parameters.each {
   println "parameter ${it.name}:"
   println it.dump()
   println "-" * 80
}

// ... or if you want the parameter by name ...
def hardcoded_param = "FOOBAR"
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
def hardcoded_param_value = resolver.resolve(hardcoded_param)

println "param ${hardcoded_param} value : ${hardcoded_param_value}"
```

This has been taken from [Use Jenkins > Jenkins Script Console > Parameterized System Groovy script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+System+Groovy+script).

The error says it contains some missing properties:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePojoPropertySite.java:63)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetPropertySafe(AbstractCallSite.java:333)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:6)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:580)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:618)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:589)
        at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
        at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
        at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
        at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:3612)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:3584)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:320)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:163)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:124)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:746)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:876)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1494)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1482)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1474)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
        at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I already tried [Running Groovy command from Jenkins using Groovy script plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429050/running-groovy-command-from-jenkins-using-groovy-script-plugin) but not working in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I <kbd>Add build step</kbd> → *Execute system Groovy script* → *Groovy command*:

```
import hudson.model.*

// get parameters
def parameters = build?.actions.find{ it instanceof ParametersAction }?.parameters
parameters.each {
   println "parameter ${it.name}:"
   println it.dump()
   println "-" * 80
}

// ... or if you want the parameter by name ...
def hardcoded_param = "FOOBAR"
def resolver = build.buildVariableResolver
def hardcoded_param_value = resolver.resolve(hardcoded_param)

println "param ${hardcoded_param} value : ${hardcoded_param_value}"
```

the output is:

```
param FOOBAR value : null
```

which is comprehensible, since where is the value of `${FOOBAR}` supposed to come from?

If I select ☑*This build is parameterized* → <kbd>Add parameter</kbd> → *String Parameter*:

- *Name*: `FOOBAR`
- *Default Value*: `FOOBAR_value`

the output is:

```
parameter FOOBAR:
<hudson.model.StringParameterValue@a6648c13 value=FOOBAR_value name=FOOBAR description=>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
param FOOBAR value : FOOBAR_value
```

Comment: Thanks. I was unclear about how to assign the value. This helped.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a "System Groovy Script", then, if I am reading the [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/groovy-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/groovy/SystemGroovy.java) correctly, the build variable should already be available and you do not need to get it via Thread which does not have the property "executable" an causes the crash.

This is also in line with the example shown [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) where the `build` variable just magically exists.

Comment: I agree with @kentis - remove the usage in thread, you get build instance "for free"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have removed the build variable declaration and updated the question. but still it's not showing any result. Can you please help me to understand where i made wrong?

Comment: While this is a valuable hint it doesn't answer the question.