# How to set Env Var in Jenkins workspace without using plugins

Tags: bash, jenkins

How can I set an environment variable which is **only** known in the jenkins workspace using a bash script (no plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  define a variable without using other Plugins by using **Groovy** .  Within your Groovy System Script, you can add following snippet for creating Env parameters:

```
import hudson.model.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def myVar = new ParametersAction([
  new StringParameterValue("The_TING", "goes_skraaa!")
])
build.addAction(myVar)
```

Then you can access this variable in the next build step which (for example) can be a windows batch command:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo The_TING=!The_TING!
```

This echo will show you "goes_skraaa!".

Comment: Any idea? groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: executable for class: java.lang.Thread

Comment: I have been using Jenkins 1.86 . This issue must be due to version difference. This issue is resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119560/jenkins-groovy-script-errorQ)