# Jenkins stop build and clean queue at specified time for specified job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a node with heavy time nightly builds. We are interested in way to stop the build and clean the queue every morning some time before team start working. All night there are a couple of builds which can have a different time to build and different results. But before the office start to work every morning we want to cancel all active jobs and clean the queue automaticaly at speicifed time for specified jobs.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins

Comment: please also see your link before post. It is usefull but solves a part of problem acording to the problem posted by me. The way described in the link cann't cancel builds and clean queue in specified time for specified job. This one can achieve one of goals but not all together

Comment: You can run it in a job schedule in the morning

Comment: I don't understand. If the job is executing now then how the job schedule can run new one before the last is not end?