# How to cancel jenkins builds based on build number of a given job using groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have to cancel the specific builds of a given job (already running or queued). Build numbers and job name are given as input.

How do I get specific job and all its build and then cancel them using groovy script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins. This might help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel queued builds and aborting executing builds using Groovy for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins)