# How can I abort all jobs with a certain name?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm attempting to set up a script to kill/abort all Jenkins jobs with a certain name in them. I've had trouble finding documentation on Jenkins classes and what's contained in them.

I know there are plugins available, but I've been directed not to use them. Otherwise, I've referred to a few semi-related questions here  ([How to stop an unstoppable zombie job on Jenkins without restarting the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456592/how-to-stop-an-unstoppable-zombie-job-on-jenkins-without-restarting-the-server/27424785)), ([Cancel queued builds and aborting executing builds using Groovy for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins)), and I attempted to rework some of the code from those, however it doesn't quite result in killed jobs:

```
import hudson.model.*

def jobList = Jenkins.instance.queue

jobList.items.findAll { it.task.name.contains('searchTerm') }.each { jobList.kill(it.task) }
```

I've also tried the following:

```
def jobname = ""
def buildnum = 85

def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobname)
 for (build in job.builds) {
     if (buildnum == build.getNumber().toInteger()){
       if (build.isBuilding()){
         build.doStop();
         build.doKill();

       }
     }

}
```

Instead of hard-killing jobs, the first script does nothing, while the second throws a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'builds' on null object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working; my second example wasn't working because I brainfarted and the job I was testing it on had no builds. :(

```
def searchTerm = ""
def matchedJobs = Jenkins.instance.items.findAll { job ->
        job.name.contains(searchTerm)
def desiredState = "stop"

if (desiredState.equals("stop")) {
            println "Stopping all current builds ${job.name}"
            for (build in job.builds) {
                if (build.isBuilding()){
                    build.doStop();
                    println build.name + " successfully stopped!"
                }
            }
}
```