# Jenkins how to set all jobs with some prefix "blah" in a view to stop if it exceeds time limit

Tags: jenkins

We have jenkin's jobs start with some prefix, some times execution getting too long. We want to stop all those jobs, how can we do it?

Comment: Does it solved your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins

Comment: @k0chan Please provide more specific details. That scripting looks to be included in job. But I need it for entire view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add timeouts to the stages which are taking more time than expected.

Example stage:

```
stage("Long-Process") {
        steps {
            timeout(time: 20, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                sh "......"
            }
        }
    }
```

The Pipleine gets aborted if this stage takes more than 20 minutes. Hope this helps.