# How can I force clear the build queue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I had server issues and had to restart a bunch of times and now I can't clear the build queue which has 200 items built up.

Doing this in the script console times out `Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()`: [Cancel queued builds and aborting executing builds using Groovy for Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins)

The queue, as reported by Jenkins, seems to be totally stale.

Where does Jenkins store this info? On disk?

Is there a script I could run in the console to fix this? Or is there a way to force clear the queue by updating a file on disk?

## EDIT

I just tried again and `Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()` worked so I don't know what was happening before.

For more info I wasn't suggesting it was timing out because there were too many jobs. Even targeting one queue item like this was timing out:

```
import hudson.model.*
def q = Jenkins.instance.queue
q.items.findAll { it.task.name.contains('my specific job name') }.each{ 
  q.cancel(it.task)
}
```

Still curious to know where the queue is held on jenkins to troubleshoot better in the future.

Comment: I've had 800+ items in the queue and run same command. Queue is wiped instantly.

Comment: How is this helpful @IanW? I'm super happy its working for you, but for me its timing out so clearly I have a problem.

Comment: Check the logs and see if they provide a clue. Just saying there should be no waiting. Don't believe it's stored on disk.