# Jenkins: cancel all Jobs triggered by another Job

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

In my build environment, I have a job A that triggers other jobs B1..N, based upon some configuration. There are up to 200 "child" jobs for an A. Both A and B are Pipeline jobs.

Sometimes, a developer realizes that he/she messed up, and wants to stop the B jobs, because their output is no longer relevant.

Is there a way to kill all jobs, that have been scheduled by one specific "parent" job?

I've already used [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305244/cancel-queued-builds-and-aborting-executing-builds-using-groovy-for-jenkins%27s) hint for a while now, but as we grow, this gets really annoying, because it might kill the wrong builds.

I've looked around in OpenBlueOcean plugin, but did not find anything in there